# Looking for an interactive javascript map solution that allows zooming in, markers and works with bitmap image (not SVG))

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, maps

Here's a nice one, but it does not allow zooming in.

[MobilyMap](http://plugindetector.com/mobilymap)

I wonder if anyone has yet implemented zooming for this plug-in ?

Ultimately if there's a guide to how I can just take a single 300DPI or
so map PNG file and then display it at say 30% of its size and
when clicking on any point on the image it will zoom into that area @ 100%
showing some markers that can be clicked on to launch an event etc.
would be great.

Would love to go with SVG or Canvas but apparently IE8 does not support it, so that's a no go then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to go free:

- You can, for example, use MapCruncher to create a bunch of tiles from a large image and use them in Bing Maps. I've created a blog post showing that procedure:

[http://build-failed.blogspot.pt/2012/03/custom-map-tiles-part-1.html](https://build-failed.blogspot.com/2012/03/custom-map-tiles-part-1.html)

- Another option is to use Zoomify with OpenLayers. Check out the demo here:

[http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/zoomify.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20130630142308/http://openlayers.org:80/dev/examples/zoomify.html)

- A little bit more hardcore is to use GDAL2Tiles. It's a python script that converts an image to tiles. Then you can use that layer with most map api.

[http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html](https://gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html)

Note: One important thing to mention that applies to each of the alternatives is that you don't have to overlay the image on top of an existing map. You can just display a base layer with your image.